# How to build tsquery with alternative in postgres full text search

Tags: postgresql

I have configured full text search on some tables in postgres DB. When I try to build tsquery with more than 1 word I get words in tsquery with & (AND) as delimiter. In effect I can't find results where is only one of words what I asked.

Example:

```
| ID | Name    | Description         | Rank |
|----|---------|---------------------|------|
| 1  |Somethink|This is very strange | 0.2  |
| 2  |Other    |This is strange a bit| 0    |
```

When I ask for "very strange" my tsquery looks like that `'very' & 'strange'`
, and ranks (ts_rank_cd) for that tsquery is more than 0 only for ID == 1, for ID == 2 is 0.

My goal is to achieve rank > 0 for 2nd sentence. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can create an `OR` version of `plainto_tsquery` by doing something along the lines of:

```
select replace(plainto_tsquery('foo bar')::text, '&', '|')::tsquery;
```

Similar to what klin advised but takes advantage of the stemming capabilities of `plainto_tsquery`.

As an aside, I believe `very` is a stop word so it won't be included in any `to_tsquery` or `plainto_tsquery` output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` instead of `AND` in the tsquery:

```
with data(d) as (
values
    ('This is very strange'),
    ('This is strange a bit')
)
select d, ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(d), 'strange | very'::tsquery)
from data

           d           | ts_rank_cd 
-----------------------+------------
 This is very strange  |        0.2
 This is strange a bit |        0.1
(2 rows)
```

You can automatically change a user input using the function `replace()`, e.g.:

```
with data(d) as (
values
    ('This is very strange'),
    ('This is strange a bit')
),
query (query) as (
values
    ('very & strange')
)
select d, ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(d), replace(query, '&', '|')::tsquery)
from data
cross join query;
```

Comment: Yes, a need to change AND to OR, but in more generic way. When user give me other query it should be done in more "automatic" way, using any function or param. I don't want to parse and change every user query.